# Event listener Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have 3 instances of the class `Foo()`. Let's call them `foo1, foo2` and `foo3` .
By default, the propriety `isReady` of `Foo()` is `false`. In the constructor of `Foo()`, there is an asynchrousnous method that sets `isReady` to true. For instance, I could be `setTimout` with different duration. After I instantiate these 3 instance, there is function called: `startMainAction()` that should be called only after `foo1.isReady = true`  and `foo2.isReady = true` and `foo3.isReady = true`
Given that the asynchronous function is undetermined, (it could be random duration), there is no way for sure the order at which the foo instances will have their propriety `isReady` set to `true`. Hence, I do not think I could use callbacks to call `startMainAction` .

How can that be achieved?

```js
 class Foo{
    
  constructor(n){
    this.isReady = false;
    setTimeout(()=>{
    this.isReady = true;
    console.log('I am ready '+n);
    }, Math.random()*1000)
  }
}
    
    
const foo1 = new Foo(1)
const foo2 = new Foo(2)
const foo3 = new Foo(3)
    
    
function startMainAction(){
    
    console.log('All fooes must be ready before I was called')
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide an actual code example to provide a better picture of what you mean?

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: It sounds, like you're looking for [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and executing actions upon [.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) of them are fulfilled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a method which adds a callback to call once you set `isReady` to true:

```
onReady(callback) {
  this.readyCallbacks.push(callback);
}
```

Then, with those three instances, call `onReady` with the `resolve` of a Promise, and call `Promise.all` on those three Promises:

```
const foos = [foo1, foo2, foo3];
Promise.all(foos.map(foo => new Promise(resolve => foo.onReady(resolve))))
  .then(startMainAction);
```

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.readyCallbacks = [];
    this.isReady = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isReady = true;
      console.log('I am ready');
      this.readyCallbacks.forEach(callback => callback());
    }, Math.random() * 1500)
  }
  onReady(callback) {
    this.readyCallbacks.push(callback);
  }
}

const foo1 = new Foo()
const foo2 = new Foo()
const foo3 = new Foo()
function startMainAction() {
  console.log('All fooes must be ready before I was called')
}
const foos = [foo1, foo2, foo3];
Promise.all(foos.map(foo => new Promise(resolve => foo.onReady(resolve))))
  .then(startMainAction);
```

I suppose you could also pass the `readyCallback` in the constructor, which would result in less code, but that doesn't seem quite appropriate, because a `Foo` (say, `foo4`) may not need a `readyCallback`, and a `readyCallback` isn't *necessary* to create an instance, it's a handler that other parts of the code request to add to an instance. (for example, if you had *two* parts of the code which had to listen for the `isReady` of `foo1`, you would need something like this `onReady` method.)

Answer (score 0):

Have the constructor method create a promise that will resolve when the condition to make the object ready happens.

Then get the promises from all of the instances and wrap them with `Promise.all` so they wait for all of them.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.isReady = false;
    this.isReadyPromise = new Promise( 
      res => setTimeout( 
        () => { console.log("I am ready"); this.isReady = true; res(true); },
        1000 + 1000 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)))
      )
    )
  }
}

const foo1 = new Foo(),
      foo2 = new Foo(),
      foo3 = new Foo();

Promise.all([ foo1.isReadyPromise, foo2.isReadyPromise, foo3.isReadyPromise ]).then(() => {
   console.log("All 3 are ready")
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add all of your instances of `Foo` into a list, an array or anything that you can iterate over. Then do something along the lines of

```
let foos = [foo1, foo2, foo3];

function WaitUntilReady(callback) {
    let ready = true;
    foreach (let foo of foos) {
        if ( !foo.isReady ) {
            ready = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ready ) {
        callback(); 
    } else {
        setTimeout(WaitUntilReady, 100); //100 miliseconds until next check
    }
}

WaitUntilReady(function() {
    //every instance is ready
});
```

Edit: using Promises seems more fancy, not sure if it really is. I'm not that much of a javascript developer so i did not even think of using them